# I have an ineffective and long code that needs optimising or trimming

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-tables, listobject

Well this is obviously part of the code but this part I keep getting lots of different error and as a beginner I don't really understand how I can adress them.

I'm in my workbook and sheet, so these are the first parameters I would like to exclude here but I get finding my self generating error rather then shorter code and so I'm asking for some help/guidens.

```
Sub SortHeaderSVA()

    Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").ListColumns("SVA").Range.Cells(1).Select
        'cant do anything of the soriting or so if I dont do above which is, well has to be a simpler way to select a header in a table that is in the current sheet and active workbook..?

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
        'also wierd, why dose the sort needs to be cleard first if there is no value earlier?

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("PR11_P3_Tabell[[#All],[SVA]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

     With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Lots of different ways to select and so but I probably don't know proper commands for typing only in VBA so I record macros and do different experiments.

Comment: If you have working code that you want to have peer reviewed for improvement, your question belongs on [codereview.se] instead, which was created just for that purpose. This site is for specific questions about problem (non-working) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select Objects unless absolutely necessary.  Remove this line:

> Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").ListColumns("SVA").Range.Cells(1).Select

`SortFields.Clear` is used to ensure that the previous settings are cleared.  After all we are adding sorts to a collection.  You can test this by commenting out the `SortFields.Clear` line and running it several times.  Next  from the Ribbon open the Data Tab and choose Sort.  You'll see that there are multiple sorts that are going to be ran whenever you call the `.Sort` method.

[image: Sort Dialog]

```
Public Sub SortHeaderSVA()

    With PR11_P3_Tabell.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=PR11_P3_Tabell.ListColumns("SVA").Range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Public Function wsPR11_P3() As Worksheet
    Set wsPR11_P3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR11_P3")
End Function

Public Property Get PR11_P3_Tabell() As ListObject
    Set PR11_P3_Tabell = wsPR11_P3.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell")
End Property
```

### Addendum

My original code declared the ListObject as a Property of the module.  The code is auto generated from a code snippet that I have.  I usually change the method signature from a Property to a Function for my post.  Like this:

```
Public Function  PR11_P3_Tabell() As ListObject
    Set PR11_P3_Tabell = wsPR11_P3.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell")
End Function
```

Comment: I really appreciate this, thank you! I'm trying to understand what public function and property are doing, I do have a feeling these line are forcing all modules to recognize what is what but I'm just guessing, is it?

Comment: @Assarelius   I have a macro that generates the code ListObject method for me I forgot that I set it up as a `Property`.  `Property Get` can be changed to `Function`.

Comment: So you mean it can be writing like this:                                                                  
                                                                                                                                `Public Function wsPR11_P3() As Worksheet
    Set wsPR11_P3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR11_P3")
End Function

Public Function Get PR11_P3_Tabell() As ListObject
    Set PR11_P3_Tabell = wsPR11_P3.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell")
End Function`

Comment: forgot to tag you in above @TinMan

Comment: @Assarelius you don't have to tag me into my own post.  I added the corrected code to my answer.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Sort an Excel Table

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SortHeaderSVA()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("PR11_P3")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell")
    Dim tlc As ListColumn: Set tlc = tbl.ListColumns("SVA")
    
    With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add _
            Key:=tlc.Range, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub SortHeaderSVANoVariables()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR11_P3").ListObjects("PR11_P3_Tabell").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add _
            Key:=.Parent.ListColumns("SVA").Range, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```